# Can i Pass Other DOM Element's Value to Server while utilizing datatable's Server Side Processing in .Net Core MVC

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-core, datatables

I have **three search boxes** (none of them are Datatable's default search box) and a search button (to send those values to my Controller), in my HTML page. I'm using jQuery **Datatable** with **Server-side** processing. Here is the script:

> BindList() is called on **Click** event of the search Box.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            BindList();
        });
        function BindList() {
            var nameSearchVal = $("#searchByName").val().trim();
            var amountSearchVal = $("#searchByAmount").val().trim();
            var durationSearchVal = $("#searchByduration").val().trim();
            var newData = {
                nameSearchText: nameSearchVal,
                amountSearchText: amountSearchVal,
                durationSearchText: durationSearchVal
            };
            $.ajax({
                url: 'url',
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                async: true,
                data: newData,
                error: function () {
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    TabData = data.TabData;
                    if ($.fn.DataTable.isDataTable("#pTable")) {
                        $('#pTable').DataTable().destroy();
                    }
                    $('#pTable').DataTable({
                        data: productData,
                        "bDestroy": true,
                        "dom": '<"top"fl>rt<"bottom"ip><"clear">',
                        "orderSequence": ["desc", "asc"],
                        "bLengthChange": false,
                        "order": [[0, 'desc']],
                        "bAutoWidth": false,
                        "searching": false,
                        "columns": [
                            { "data": "id", "name": "Id", "searchable": false, "visible": false },
                            ---REST OF THE Cols---
                        ],
                        "initComplete": function () {
                            var dataTable = $('#productTable').DataTable();
                            $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
                        }
                        //"fnDrawCallback": function () {
                        //}
                    })
                }
            })
        }
```

I tried adding `"serverSide": true` in the above approach, but I'm getting the following error message...

> datatables.min.js:62 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'data' of null
> Here is my MVC Controller where I'm getting the TextBoxes values...

```
 [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult GetProductListing(string nameSearchText = "", string amountSearchText = "", 
        string durationSearchText = "")
        {
            *****NOt Getting These Values******
            //int draw = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["draw"]);
            //int StartIndex = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form["start"]);
            //string SortDir = Request.Form["order[0][dir]"];
            
            //Rest Of the code
        }
```

I want to send data from those search boxes when I change the page or sort any column in the Datable too. Right now I'm not getting any values from the Datatable. As I said, I tried to add Server-side parameter in the Datatable but still no luck.

> **Help me with this. I'm new to this Plugin, so I don't have any idea about it** Or should I try a different approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use "data" function to add extra fields

```
$('#pTable').DataTable({
"processing": true,
"serverSide": true,
"ajax": {
    "url": "url",
    "type": "POST",
    "error": function (xhr, error, code) {
        // show error message
    },
    "data": function (d) {
        d.searchByName = $('#searchByName').val();
        //add whatever you want
    }
},
"bDestroy": true,   
    // config ...
});
```